# How can I bind keys for pasting different texts in Linux?

Tags: linux, hotkeys, clipboard, paste

When I answer my numerous e-mails I usually choose from 5-6 sentences, and simply copy-paste them. It would be useful to bind them to hot keys, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

Is there a clipboard manager or other mechanism/program that can carry this out?

Comment: Linux, X Window, or something else? There is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Found your answer on the following site.

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1367

tried it myself (glipper) it autoloads after install, and works fine. Just copy anything and then copy another, it saves them in its storage.

my icon appeared in the bottom right corner, next to my printer utility (Debian), so you may have to look for it if you aren't using mint.

good luck